# Using Gauss's lemma to show if p(a) = p(b) = p(c) = p(d) = 5, there is no integer k with p(k) = 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm attempting to prove this:

> Let p(x) be a monic polynomial with integer coefficients. Suppose that there are distinct integers a, b, c, d with p(a) = p(b) = p(c) = p(d) = 5. There is no integer k with p(k) = 8.

I have a hint saying to use Gauss's lemma, but I don't know how. Just plain following my nose gave me this:

> Consider the polynomial $p'(x) = p(x) - 5$. $p'(a) = p'(b) = p'(c) = p'(d) = 0$. Therefore, $p'(x) = (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)q(x)$, where $q(x)$ is another polynomial. Suppose to the contrary that there exists an integer $k$ so that $p(k) = 8$. Then $p'(k) - 3 = (k-a)(k-b)(k-c)(k-d)q(k) - 3 = 0$. So if $p''(x) = p'(x) - 3,$ then $p''(x) = (x-3)r(x)$ for some polynomial $r(x)$.

I'm looking for a contradiction, but I don't know where it is. Am I even on the right track with this?

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use the notations $p'$ and $p''$ as it's hard not to interpret them as derivatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You have already got $(k-a)(k-b)(k-c)(k-d)q(k)=3$. Now $k-a, k-b, k-c, k-d$ are four distinct integers whose product is a factor of $3$.

Comment: I know how to use that and the fact 3 is prime to say that I can only have 3 distinct factors, which is a contradiction, but I'm lost as to where I've used Gauss's lemma if I do that..which makes me doubtful of my idea's legitimacy.

Comment: @Xindaris You need to know that $q(X)$ is also a polynomial with integer coefficients. If $q(k)$ is just some rational number then there's no contradiction